# cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes error - ( Live Tex | TexMaker)

Tags: compiling, compilation-error

Whatever tex file i am trying to compile i get the same error. I am using Live Tex and TexMaker. Any ideas on what to do to solve this problem?

```
! Emergency stop.
<read 4>
l.33 \begin{document}
^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
21785 strings out of 492609
424718 string characters out of 6132818
537429 words of memory out of 5000000
25347 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
4044 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
55i,0n,73p,839b,217s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Check above in the log-file to see which file it can't find. (And imho better don't use nonstopmode so that latex can stop and tell you which file is missing directly).

Comment: Take a look in the log-file if you dont mind: https://pastebin.com/iA5Fp6wj  I couldnt find something useful.

Comment: Looks like a problem with minted. Probably the test for pygmentize failed. You should really deactivated nonstopmode to get a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same Problem.
I solve This as Follows:

1. add the parameter "--shell-escape" in Terminal to compile it.
2. or add this paramater to the TexMaker Compile choice.
   I don't use TexMaker SO this is what i can do.